# Import Cv2 not working despite opencv installed

Tags: python, macos, opencv, importerror

I have installed OpenCV with the command `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and when I run the command pip list I see `opencv-contrib-python` has been installed and yet `import cv2` does not work for me and it throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\[filename here\]", line 1, in \<module\>
import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

and I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling OpenCV and it still does not work. I tried different development environments like Pycharm and visual studio code. I also have my pip upgraded and my OpenCV is version 4.5.5 which is the latest version. I have tried using python 3.10 and 3.7 but the same error still shows. I have also tried using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
```

which was recommended in some answers and I have tried just installing opencv-python and using that and the same error still shows. I checked and I have cv2 in
my folder

but despite this, it keeps showing no module named cv2 every time I try to run import cv2

I use macOS Monterey version 12.2.1 and for my terminal, I use Darwan OS which is a Linux distro.

I tried:
`pip install opencv-python`

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

putting this at the first lines of code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
```

Comment: These kind of problem usually are result of Virtual Environments where one does not activate the venv in question before `pip install`ing the library. Are sure you're good on that part?

Comment: Do `python -V` to make sure which version you're running.  And, BTW, Darwin is NOT a Linux distro.  It is a version of Unix derived from BSD.

Comment: @MSH how do I activate the venv? and pip install works for me. It shows successfully installed and when I go to the path where it was installed in I can see opencv installed there.

Comment: @TimRoberts when i run python -V it shows Python 3.10.4

Comment: @greenstrial are you `pip install`ing opencv on a separate terminal or a terminal on pycharm itself?

Comment: on my main terminal on my computer. @MSH

Comment: @greenstrial Try `terminal` on bottom on the pycharm to open one where your environment loaded. then `pip install`.

Comment: @MSH it works for my pycharm. for vs code it does not work even after I created a virtual environment and installed opencv-contrib-python it still throws the same error when I try to run it but for some reason when I run my program on the terminal  with python3 programname.py it does not show any errors. I made sure the virtual environment was the python interpreter. the venv is activated on vs code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a vscode user. So I have no idea how to setup projects in it. But since it works, I am pretty sure you will figure out how to make it run with vscode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `python2.7`. As the [manual](https://breakthrough.github.io/Installing-OpenCV/) says: "Currently, only the Python 2 version of the cv2 module is built and included in the latest release."

You can only use `python3` if you manually build from source code.

Comment: Looking to the documentation I couldn't see where it says one cannot use `python3`. Regardless my `python` version is `3.10.0` and I successfully installed `cv2` version`4.5.5`

Comment: Tried to change my version to python2.7 and it still does not work. Even changed my interpreter in vs code to Python2.7 and it does not work.